# Repair MBR of a remote virtual server

Tags: boot, partitioning, mbr, windows-server-2016

I want to preface my question by saying that I have very, very limited experience with virtual servers of any kind.

Anyway, here's my problem.
I inherited a virtual server with a 1TB disk, partitioned in 40GB for the OS and the rest for data. The OS partition filled up pretty quickly so my idea was to repartition it, since the data partition was 90% empty and I needed the space.
Couldn't use the Windows disk manager (it allowed me to shrink the data partition, but not extend the OS partition). So I turned to a 3rd party software (AOMEI Partition Assistant Lite Edition 7.5 if it's important). I got it working, everything got partitioned correctly, but then, after rebooting the server, I couldn't access it through Remote Desktop.

The company hosting the sever has a recovery mode, that basically sets up a new installation on the same server, where the two old partitions are accessible as another disk (so there's a total of four partitions now - the C, where the fresh OS resides, D, where the system reserved partition of the old installation is, and two more - the old OS partition and the old data partition).
Once I log into this recovery mode I could see that the partitions are correct, but every time I try to boot in regular mode, the server is inaccessible.

The question is - is this really an MBR problem or is there something else that I broke through my partitioning? And if it is an MBR problem, how can I fix it?

Comment: Did the server have exactly two partitions? Normally Server 2016 (and all recent Windows versions in general) should have another, small (~100M) "System" partition with no drive letter but with a few hidden files such as `BOOTMGR`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, missed that one in the first paragraph - it has a System reserved partition (~500MB) and the two big ones.